# Raspberry pi : Using Sense Hat sensor , How to detect acceleration?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I'm student

Sensor and Raspberry Pi are inexperienced because they are first used.
I would like to install Raspberry Pi inside the car to get the car's acceleration.
We will measure the acceleration of the car and send it to the Android application.
I have a 'Sense Hat' sensor and I think I need to use the Sense Hat's IMU sensor.

I plan to use Python for the language, can you help me with how to proceed?

Comment: You can try to follow this guide: https://projects.raspberrypi.org/en/projects/getting-started-with-the-sense-hat/9

Comment: We cater to specific questions. How to do _X_ is not very specific. Research approaches, code some of them, if you have a specific problem come back. Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. See [Why is "can someone help me" not an actual question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: thank you, i'm sorry
the next question will be more specific !